# Should I use the same detail ViewController to work both modally and when pushed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

This seems to be the patten used throughout Apples applications; Creation of a new record is done through a modal View which needs to be saved or canceled to continue, and editing a record is done through a view pushed onto the navigation stack.

It doesn't seem right to be basically duplicating my ViewController for 'add' and 'edit' but there are several differences in how pushed and modal ViewControllers work which complicate things.

How should I be doing this so it can cover both bases?

-

Differences include.

When pushed onto the stack the navBar appears at the top of the View and can be configured to contain the cancel/save buttons. When presented modally this is not the case so to duplicate the interface a toolbar needs to be created separately and close/save buttons added to this instead.

When dismissing a pushed view we send a message to the navigation controller `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, when dismissing a modal view we send a message to self `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: How exactly are "things complicated" between pushing and presenting modal?

Comment: Edited question with more detail

Comment: I'd approach that by defining a protocol (trapperViewDismisser) that allowed the view controller to indicate it was ready to be dismissed.

Then, conform to trapperViewDismisser and set delegate to self.

This moves the differences out to the class which displays the VC (which already knows the differences anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the UIToolbar in InterfaceBuilder, and then just hide it in viewDidLoad when self.navigationController is not nil.

As for dismissing, you could have something like:

```
- (void)didCancel {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] || [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This will shortcircuit if your viewcontroller is part of a navigationcontrol, and use dismissModalViewControllerAnimated otherwise.

This should work for your cancel button. For your save button, it is useful to call some sort of delegate method such as:

```
- (void)didSave {
    // do your saving juju here
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewController:didSave:]) {
        [self.delegate viewController:self didSave:whatJustGotSaved];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // noop if currently modal
}
```

In the delegate's implementation then, you can put:

```
- (void)viewController:(UIViewController*)viewController didSave:(NSObject*)whatJustGotSaved {
    // do stuff with parameters
    [self.modalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // noop if not modal
}
```